# Codeigniter Sending Query, MySQL is receiving a different query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

So I'm completely puzzled at this. I am writing an application in Codeigniter and so far I haven't had any issues except now I am experiencing two.

Part 1

If I send the query :

```
UPDATE `locations`
SET `address` = '', `city` = 'asdf2', `province` = '', `postal_code` = '', `country` = '', `telephone` = '', `r_id` = '3'
WHERE `location_id` = '20'
```

(via $this->db->query() and $this->db->last_query() confirms it) the MySQL logs show it received the query:

```
UPDATE `locations`
SET `address` = '', `city` = '', `province` = '', `postal_code` = '', `country` = '', `telephone` = '', `r_id` = '3'
WHERE `location_id` = '20'
```

Obviously the value for city are different and I don't understand where/how that value is being changed.

Part 2

I have noticed also that occasionally when inserting data (to only certain tables - this one being one of them) it inserts duplicates (the first correct, the second empty).

I suspect the two issues are related and perhaps tied to the particular tables (given the application works just fine other than these two issues.

---

Update 1: I looked a closer look at the MySQL query logs and it appears as though whats actually happening is that the request completes successfully and then completely repeats itself (will all null values) from connection, init, queries and quit.

Update 2: On a hunch, I tried it in FireFox and the issues disappear... So that rules out CI/MySQL/PHP...Still not sure what's going on or whats causing it though.

Comment: You may want to post the code that generates these queries. So much as I know, CI doesn't have any phantom programs that are known for things like this.

Comment: You're most likely not setting the parameters correctly

Comment: I look a closer look at the mySQL query logs and it appears as though whats actually happening is that the request completes successfully and then repeats itself (will all null values) hence the insert issues and potentially the update issues.

No clue what could be causing it though.

Comment: [Tutorial](http://codesamplez.com/database/codeigniter-activerecord)

Comment: Then we need to see both ur `ajax` or `form action` && your server side code. I wouldn't say it completely rules it out, but you're on a path

Comment: So... it's not AJAX. Just a standard POST request.

Comment: Where do you echo the last query from CI? It might be the case the query is called from CI after that. May be if you have a your Core Model class or some where in controller. First print last query in different places and see.